# When trying to determine if a network is scale-free, the Kolmogorov–Smirnov returns p-val of 0.0

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am trying to determine if a network is scale free using scipy's kstest. On a very small test network, I was able to achieve a p-value of 0.1875. However, on the network of interest, the p-val is always 0.0.

To investigate, I used NetworkX to generate a scale-free graph of 1000 nodes, but even then I'm getting a 0.0 for p-val:

```
import networkx as nx
from scipy.stats import kstest
import powerlaw

graph = nx.scale_free_graph(1000)

deg_dist = sorted([deg for node, deg in graph.degree()], reverse=True)
fit = powerlaw.Fit(deg_dist, discrete=True)
alpha = fit.power_law.alpha
xmin = fit.power_law.xmin
test, p = kstest(deg_dist, "powerlaw", args = (alpha, xmin),N=len(deg_dist))


print("Test: " + str(test) + "\nP: " + str(p))
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Edit: Using nx to generate a scale-free graph of 10 nodes results in a p-val of 0.000568. It seems like the p-val is inversely proportional to graph size, so I must be doing something wrong here.